# Unique column with autoincrement in sqllite

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I am working in an android application which uses sqllite database. In my Db in a table i need a unique column. But some some times this column with unique will insert null values. Instead, I need an autoincrement value to be inserted in this column .

Please give a solution in the table script to generate a table with a column supporting both unique and autoincrement .

Answer (score 3):

Just like below in SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

More Information:The `MS SQL Server` uses the `IDENTITY keyword` to perform an `auto-increment` feature.

and SQLite like below Query:

```
CREATE TABLE failed_banks(id integer primary key, name text, city text, state text, zip integer, acquired_by text, close_date date, updated_date date);
```

More Information: A column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will `auto-increment` in `SQLite`.

Comment: @Arun "PRIMARY KEY" defined Uniqueness. that's it

Comment: OK...My requirement is also to use insert or replace into TABLE with the unique column...Will that work ??

Comment: @Arun yes when you added any record then it'll automatically increment by +1. that's it

Comment: Ok...I want to insert an auto incremented value to id integer primary key when I supply null value to this column...Is that possible ?

Comment: @Arun why r u doing this auto increment manually. You do not need to passed this id value.

Comment: Yea..that's my requirement... I want to insert an unique value to that column when I have null values returned from my web service...Any solution ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45358/discussion-between-m-d-and-arun)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a column where you can insert and update and that column will still hold uniqueness then you have to implement it in that way.

First make that column UNIQUE, then in case of insert make sure you have some mechanism to add unique values to that column. In case of update and insert you need to catch the unique value exception and make sure you take proper action in case of exception.

Some approaches you can take are:

If you need unique integer then at the time of insert always go for max value in the column and add 1 to insert new value. In case of update integer value you need to confirm that value is not existing by fetch the value first for that integer and then update if not added already. If value is there then you need to have a logic to have another unique value.

If value of column is not integer or number instead it is text, then you have to handle it better in both insert and update by first checking the existence and then update/insert.

Answer (score 0):

**Sort answer**: you can't except if it a primary key field.

If it is `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` and *auto-incremented*, then you have no choice except making it your primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( your_field_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ... )
```

The `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` thing here makes it primary key as will as auto-incremented.

The Sqlite database has a keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` which cannot be used except with association to the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.